# /Boot/ folder has 0 bytes of free memory Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

My Ubuntu 16.04 laptop shows me warnings about there being no memory left in the `/boot/` folder. Is there anything I can do (delete unneeded files etc.) to resolve the situation?

Comment: Please post the exact error message that you’re getting, and maybe say something about the history of this problem — e.g., is it a brand new install, or has it been working fine for some time?  Have you done anything recently that might have caused/triggered this problem? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: This sounds like `sudo apt-get autoremove` could help